# Cross analysis and average of multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been trying this for hours and can't seem to get my head around how I should proceed. I have this table here:

[image]

Volha stands for volume by hectare, Tiha is for plants per hectare. BOP, SEPM and PET are plant families.

What I am looking to do is to get a table where I have the average value for the volume per hectare and plants per hectare IN each of the 13 blocks for each of the 3 plant families. example : the average value for volume per hectare of BOP in bloc 7. Final table should look like this, except this one says '' total volume'' or ''total plants'' instead of average.

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question and show the results for the data you have provided.  In addition, it would be quite helpful if the data was inserted as a text table, rather than an image.  SQL Fiddle can also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I underestimated your objective, simply run an aggregate query grouping by blocks.

```
SELECT NOBLOC, SUP_HA,
       AVG(TigehaBOP) AS NOM_BOP,
       AVG(TigehaPET) AS NOM_PET,
       AVG(TigehaSEP) AS NOM_SEP,
       AVG(VolhaBOP) AS VOL_BOP,
       AVG(VolhaPET) AS VOL_PET,
       AVG(VolhaSEP) AS VOL_SEP
FROM Table
GROUP BY NOBLOC, SUP_HA
```

*Do note: SQL does not merge cells such as suggested header and columns have been prefixed to avoid duplicate aliases.*

Comment: Thank you so much.  I don't understand why yours works and my attempts didn't , however. I was trying exactly the same thing. Would it have changed anything if you had not put '' NOBLOC'' and ''SUP_HA'' first in that query ?

Comment: Glad to help! Order does not matter as long as `GROUP BY` contains corresponding column. But columns will only appear if specified in `SELECT`.